# jQuery dialog...... can't make more than 3 popups

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

Currently I'm using jQuery dialog.  It works fine, but I can't make more than 3 popups.  Does anyone know what the reason is and how to make more popups?

Maybe I have to edit jQuery dialog's javascript code.  But I don't know where to do this.

Comment: can you break down what you're trying to achieve into a fiddle?

Comment: There's no reason why jQuery would, by design, prevent you from opening more than 3 dialogs. You must have an error in your code somehwere.

Comment: Post your jQuery and HTML code. So we can help u.